# send data, url, and method to axios as arguments

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to make custom request with axios and pass the method, url and body as arguments like that

```
const response = await axios({ url, body, method });
```

but the body doesnot reach to the backend. what is the right way to send data like that?

Answer (score 0):

The config property you're searching for is called `data` not `body`. Rename your variable to data and pass it or don't use the object shorthand operator and rename it to data. Like this:

```
const response = await axios({ url, data: body, method });
```

In the [axios documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config) is a list of all available properties.